# How to allocate vector greater than 2Gb

Tags: r, memory, limit, r-daisy

I was trying to carry out a command in R when I received this error:

```
d <- daisy(demo, metric = "gower",stand = FALSE, type = list(), weights = 1)
  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.3 Gb
```

Is there a way to allocate more memory to R? Mine is a 64 bit R on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: How much RAM in your computer?

Comment: 8.00GB (7.69 Usable) @Pascal

Comment: Check `memory.limit()` function.

Comment: remove unused objects, stop unused programs (firefox, dropbox, etc...), change OS - so that you have as much RAM as possible available for R...

Comment: Make a quick trip to the electronics market and by some more RAM?

Comment: You might also checkout the `data.table` package. It plays nicer with larger data (but I  don't know if it would help you in this case).